# How to display selected choices from a field of a Django ModelForm, on the basis of attribute value of choice object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

As part of a Django web app, I am working on a page that would show the user a list of jobs that can be filtered by category and/or subcategory. Each category has several subcategories, each subcategory has only one category. A job can have several categories/subcategories. So, the idea is to get a filtering form that looks like in the image below:

[image]

Below is what I have tried so far.

### In models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = u'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = u'subcategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    subcategories = models.ManyToManyField(Subcategory, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### In forms.py:

```
class JobModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['categories', 'subcategories']
        widgets = {}
        for field in fields:
            widgets[field] = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
```

### In HTML template:

#### Method 1:

```
<form method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for category in form.categories %}
        <div>
            {{ category }}
            {% for subcategory in form.subcategories %}
                <div style="text-indent: 2em">
                    {{ subcategory }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Because the subcategories are not selected according to their category, all subcategories (related or not to current category in the loop) are shown below each category. The good thing in this method is that choices are displayed correctly (with the checkbox):

[image]

#### Method 2:

```
<form method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for category in form.categories.field.queryset %}
        <div>
        {{ category }}
            {% for subcategory in form.subcategories.field.queryset %}
            {% if subcategory.category == category %}
            <div style="text-indent: 2em">
                {{ subcategory }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Now, the subcategories are selected according to their category (being equal to the current category in the loop), but we only see the names of the categories and subcategories, these are not choices that can be clicked:

[image]

So, it seems that a working code could be some combination of method 1 and method 2, but in spite of a lot of trying and searching (including related Stack Overflow questions), I haven't been able to figure it out. Could you help me with this please?

### Additional related questions:

- In Django admin, every time I add a Job, I have to select subcategories AND categories. However, given that every subcategory object already has an category attribute, how can I make sure that categories are automatically selected based on the subcategories I select?
- Also, as filtering by categories and subcategories seems very common on the web, I am wondering about how it is done in general. Is there a more direct or standard way to achieve this in Django (without third-party libraries quite yet as I am just getting started learning Django)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not a different form for each category? Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: @StefanoTrv, thank you for your suggestion. As I have just started learning Django, could you please elaborate on how I could use formsets in my case? Perhaps in an answer?